# SQL Server date datatype default and constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having some difficulty with SQL Server where I am creating a table called `GUEST` and using `date` as a data type, not null and has a default value of 'today' and a constraint of the date must be equal or later than 01 dec 2010.

However, I am encountering a problem when I tried to test by insert a row with default values.

How can I let SQL Server to show the current date instead of the default `getDate()` which defaults to 1900-01-01 which conflicts with my constraint condition of date must be later than 01 -dec-2010

```
 INSERT INTO GUEST 
 VALUES('John' ,'');
```

Results in an error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chk_DATEJOINED". The conflict occurred  table "dbo.GUEST", column 'dateJoined'.

I have done some code to show

```
CREATE TABLE GUEST
(
    [...]
    guestNum int NOT NULL IDENTITY(5,1),
    name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    dateJoined date NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
    [...]

    CONSTRAINT chk_DATEJOINED 
        CHECK (dateJoined >= CAST('01-dec-2010' as DATETIME))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in several ways.

1) like everyone else has pointed out.  State which columns you want to populate and skipping the dateJoined column.

```
insert into Employee ( name ) values ( 'John' )
```

2) Use the default keyword as the value.

```
insert into Employee ( name, dateJoined ) values ( 'John', default )
```

The default keyword is useful if you're building an SQL statement in code and want the column list explicitly set.  Default keyword defaults to null if there isn't a default constraint on the column so watch out for columns declared as not null.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST('' as DATE) returns 1900-01-01;
```

So what your insert statement is trying to insert implicitly is 1900-01-01 since you passed the value ''.  If you want the insert to use the default value you have to exclude it completely.

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(Name) VALUES('John');
```

Would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to try the default value,no need of passing value to the date field. ' ' is a valid string character and it becomes '1900-01-01' while converting to date type.Also mention the column names in the Insert query while making the insertion like below. If you not mentioning the column names in the INSERT statement,SQL server will try to insert data in the default order of columns .

```
  INSERT INTO Employee (name, ..OtherColumns) --mention the name of other columns if required 
   VALUES ('John',OtherColumnsValues)
```

Comment: Hi, i used (' ' ) to test for default value and it shows 1900-01-01 which conflicts with my constraint condition of date must be later than 01 -dec-2010

Comment: ' '  a valid string character. That is why I told you, if you wanted to check the default value ,do not passant value to that column. SQL server will populate the default value to that column for every Insert .

Answer (score 0):

You should use this

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_test(name) VALUES('John');
```

Your query equal to `INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('John' , CAST('' as datetime))`

When you use the query `INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('John' ,'');` `SQLServer` will try convert `''` to datatime, and that is `1900-01-01` so you get that error.

Comment: Hi, i used (' ' ) to test for default value and it shows 1900-01-01 which conflicts with my constraint condition of date must be later than 01 -dec-2010

Comment: @jukira '' is not default value. It is a NULL value, and it equal to  `cast('' as datetime)` - equal to `1900-01-01`.

Answer (score 0):

try this insert statement.
    INSERT INTO #EMPLOYEE (name)
     VALUES('John' );